# Bubble sorting an array with nulls in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm trying to create a bubble sort with nulls in the middle in C.
The code works ok when the array is ordered in a way so the nulls are at the end of the array (hense the "continue" condition works).

My array looks like this: [John,David,NULL,Grace,NULL,NULL]
on which I run this function:

```
void SortContacts(char * people[]) {
    int i,j;
    char *tempswap;
    for (i=0; i<storage-1; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<storage-i-1; j++) {
                if (people[j+1]==NULL) {
                    continue;
                }
            if (strcmp(people[j],people[j+1]) > 0) {
                tempswap = people[j];
                people[j] = people[j+1];
                people[j+1] = tempswap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When executing with the NULL in the middle of the array the exe crashes.

Comment: If `people[j+1]` is `NULL` for some `j`, what will `people[j]` be on the next iteration?

Comment: Your logic requires to push NULL to the end, so if one pointer is NULL you should think of it as greater than any other non-NULL string.

Comment: There will come a point where `j` is the index of the first `NULL` and `j + 1` is the index of `"Grace"`. Think about what will happen when you pass that `NULL` pointer at index `j` to `strcmp`.

Comment: `if (people[j+1]==NULL) {continue;}` it continued now you are at `j+1` as `j`
and what do you expect

Comment: if (people[j] == NULL or strcmp(people[j],people[j+1]) > 0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot `strcmp` a `NULL` value. Although you are guarding against a `strcmp` of `people[j+1]` being `NULL`, you don't check `people[j]`.

Try the following (untested), which simply provides a `strcmp` function which treats a `NULL` like "".

```
int
strcmpwithnull(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    return strcmp(a?a:"", b?b:"");
}

void SortContacts(char * people[]) {
    int i,j;
    char *tempswap;
    for (i=0; i<storage-1; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<storage-i-1; j++) {
        if (strcmpwithnull(people[j],people[j+1]) > 0) {
                tempswap = people[j];
                people[j] = people[j+1];
                people[j+1] = tempswap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a `NULL` to be treated as *greater* than any other string, then try (again untested):

```
int
strcmpwithnull(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    if (a == b)
        return 0; /* handles 2 NULLs and two strings at the same location */
    else if (!a)
        return 1;
    else if (!b)
        return -1;
    else
        return strcmp(a, b);
}
```

If you want them to be less than any other string (including the empty string), swap the `return 1` and `return -1`.

Comment: Great, thank you, that was my first thought, treating a NULL as an empty string but couldn't get it to work as expected.

Comment: I upvoted, but I don't like your `return strcmp(a?a:"", b?b:"");` at all. It leaves true empty strings `""` indeterminately ordered w.r.t. the `NULL`s. Your second solution is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem

```
            if (people[j+1]==NULL) 
            {
                continue;
            }
```

You need to check both `j` and `j+1`
Also consider What if you have a `NULL` in the head of the array ? or you have 2 `NULLs` one after another

So you need also to check the `j` not only the `j+1`

you should also check the`j`isn't `null`

Comment: You need to check *both*. But you can't simply always continue if either is NULL or they won't bubble up.

Comment: @NirTzezana No probs , but take a look at abligh's answer it is better!

Answer (score 0):

You want to end up with the nulls at the right of the array. This can be achieved by making nulls strictly greater than any string. You have to encode this into the comparison function.

```
int cmp(const char *x, const char *y)
{   if(x == 0) return 1;
    if(y == 0) return -1;
    return strcmp(x, y);
}
```

Comment: If the two strings are both null, it should return 0.

Comment: Not required for sorting. This is not meant to replace strcmp, just to use in sorting algorithm. In your answer you use `>0` only for example.